# Save the current theme value locally using angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Actually i want to save the current theme what the user activated in the browser. When the next time the user comes in and opens the browser or if the browser refreshes automatically i don't to change the saved theme to default theme. For that i have tried with the below code snippets. I am using angular with material. Can anyone help me out?

This is my code what i have tried till now.

app.component.html

```
<div id="app-main" class="app-main full-height"
   [ngClass]="{'fixed-header' : AppConfig.fixedHeader,
               'nav-collapsed' : AppConfig.navCollapsed,
               'nav-behind' : AppConfig.navBehind,
               'layout-boxed' : AppConfig.layoutBoxed,
               'theme-gray' : AppConfig.theme == 'gray',
               'theme-dark' : AppConfig.theme == 'dark',
               'sidebar-sm' : AppConfig.sidebarWidth == 'small',
               'sidebar-lg' : AppConfig.sidebarWidth == 'large'}">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

header.component.html

```
<li>
                    <label class="theme-option-check">
                        <input type="radio" name="theme" value="light" [(ngModel)]="AppConfig.theme" (change)="changeTheme(currentTheme)">
                        <span class="theme-option-item">
                            <span class="overlay">
                                <mat-icon>check</mat-icon>
                            </span>
                            <span><i class="far fa-sun"></i>&nbsp; Light Mode</span>
                        </span>
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label class="theme-option-check">
                        <input type="radio" name="theme" value="dark" [(ngModel)]="AppConfig.theme" (change)="changeTheme(currentTheme)">
                        <span class="theme-option-item">
                            <span class="overlay">
                                <mat-icon>check</mat-icon>
                            </span>
                            <span><i class="fas fa-adjust"></i>&nbsp; Dark Mode</span>
                        </span>
                    </label>
                </li>
```

header.component.ts

```
public currentTheme: string = APPCONFIG.theme; //by default here i am managing default color as light
ngOnInit() {
    this.currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('APISec-Theme');
    APPCONFIG.theme = this.currentTheme;
  }

changeTheme(t: any) {
    if (t !== null) {
      console.log('Select correct theme');
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem('APISec-Theme', t);
      console.log('t', t);
    }
  }
```

When i click on the any one of the two radio buttons then in the console its showing as 'null' value. So how to change the null to current selected value like if i select on Light then the theme should change light color and when i select on dark mode then it should change as dark theme. Please help me. Also the selected value should be in the browser localstorage even if the browser refreshes.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried passing AppConfig.theme to (change)="changeTheme( AppConfig.theme)" ? that should work

Comment: @user8351493, i tried it but its not working.

Comment: If you are storing it in local storage and then trying to fetch the value after a refresh or reopening the browser, you will not get the value as local storage will be cleared out.

Comment: APPCONFIG.theme it is in uppercase in component and capitalised in template

Comment: I used browser cache to store that.

Comment: @user8351493, hey man thanks it worked actually. I have removed if condition then it got worked. Thanks for your help.